# Native GCC 5 binaries too big (libexec)

Tags: linux, gcc, binary, native, gnu

So I am on an old CentOS 6.6 distro, and compiled GCC 5.2 from source.
When I install it, it creates its 5.2.0 subfolder under libexec, but the binaries cc1 and cc1 plus are gigantic!

Here is how I built it

```
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=./gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr2/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux-gnu/5.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-redhat-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../configure
--prefix=/usr2
--disable-multilib
--enable-languages=c,c++
--enable-gnu-unique-object
--disable-dssi
--enable-libstdcxx-threads
--enable-libstdcxx-time
--enable-shared
--enable-__cxa_atexit
--disable-libunwind-exceptions
--disable-libada
--host=i686-redhat-linux-gnu
--build=i686-redhat-linux-gnu
--target=i686-redhat-linux-gnu
--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
--with-arch=i686
--enable-linker-build-id
--with-system-zlib
--with-default-libstdcxx-abi=gcc4-compatible
Thread model: posix
gcc version 5.2.0 (GCC)
```

Here is an ls from 4.4.7 in the distro

```
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 8566416 Jul 23 00:19 cc1
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 9574772 Jul 23 00:19 cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  101596 Jul 23 00:19 collect2
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 9419280 Jul 23 00:19 f951
```

And here is the same from the newly compiled 5.2.0

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 102532928 Dec 11 16:48 cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 109000772 Dec 11 16:48 cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2033844 Dec 11 16:48 collect2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root      4096 Dec 11 16:48 install-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       995 Dec 11 16:48 liblto_plugin.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        22 Dec 11 16:48 liblto_plugin.so -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root        22 Dec 11 16:48 liblto_plugin.so.0 -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    235508 Dec 11 16:48 liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  98350432 Dec 11 16:48 lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   2288396 Dec 11 16:48 lto-wrapper
```

cc1, cc1plus and lto1 are 100MB each.
Is this normal for 5.2?
Why does this happen?

Thanks to @Marc Glisse comment, I ran a file on both binaries

```
5.2.0/cc1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped

4.4.7/cc1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped
```

Is this *stripped* that makes the difference?
What configuration flag am I missing?

Comment: The thing with embedded systems is that you don't actually program *on* those systems, you program *for* them. That's why there's such things as cross-compiling.

Comment: Thank you Joachim. I didn't know cross-compiling. I did a quick search and it is not really well documented how to do it.
Apparently I need to make a 686-to-486 compiler, possibly linking to the correct kernel headers? Maybe binutils too?

Still when deploying and testing we sometimes compile on the machine itself, so it's convenient to have the compiler (we are not talking about a POS machine here).
So I would still solve the size issue I mention.

Comment: What does `file /path/to/cc1` say?

Comment: @MarcGlisse /usr2/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux-gnu/5.2.0/cc1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped


/usr/libexec/gcc/i686-redhat-linux/4.4.7/cc1: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, stripped

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to @MarcGlisse for pointing me in the right direction.

No matter how you configure GCC, unless you install with

```
make install-strip
```

the binaries will be full of symbols.
Installing the stripped version brought the size down 70%.

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 19749196 Dec 14 13:01 cc1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 21057676 Dec 14 13:01 cc1plus
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   507336 Dec 14 13:01 collect2
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 14 13:01 install-tools
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      995 Dec 14 13:01 liblto_plugin.la
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 Dec 14 13:01 liblto_plugin.so -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       22 Dec 14 13:01 liblto_plugin.so.0 -> liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    76972 Dec 14 13:01 liblto_plugin.so.0.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18930924 Dec 14 13:01 lto1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   693024 Dec 14 13:01 lto-wrapper
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 14 13:01 plugin
```